# Trying to use TwitterLib 25 with GAS

Tags: api, google-apps-script

So using the following simple code to just test tweet to Twitter. I have signed up for the account and have all the pertinent info. The only thing I may be doing wrong is putting the wrong key/secret in the wrong area. Here is my Twitter dev setup:

[image]

This is my simple code:

```
function sendTweet(status) {
  status = "Is this a cool tweet?";

  var twitterKeys = {
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: '**************************',
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: '**************************',
    TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: '**************************-**************************',
    TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET: '**************************',
  };

  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  props.setProperties(twitterKeys);

  var service = new Twitterlib.OAuth(props);

  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var response = service.sendTweet(status);

    if (response) {
      Logger.log('Tweet ID ' + response.id_str);
    } else {
      // Tweet could not be sent
      // Go to View -> Logs to see the error message
    }
  }
}
```

My consumer key/secret -> API Key and Secret below and my access token/secret -> Access Token and Secret below. I am seeing the following error which doesn't give me a lot to go on as far as errors and been fighting to figure this out for days.

```
Send tweet failure. Error was:
{"name":"Exception"}

options were:
{"method":"POST","payload":"status=Is%20this%20a%20cool%20tweet%3F","headers":{"Authorization":"OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"**************************\", oauth_nonce=\"**************************\", oauth_signature=\"**************************%3D\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1644456180\", oauth_token=\"**************************-**************************\", oauth_version=\"1.0\""},"escaping":false}
```

Any help or resources would be a huge help in figuring this out!! Thank you in advance.

phi

Comment: This example is not reproducible

Comment: Ok, I am just trying to see what I am doing wrong or what resources I can get to help figure this out. The error being displayed back is too generic and very little info I could find. Do you have any recent examples of using TwitterLib with GAS?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out being I needed to turn on essential API access in the Twitter API Developer site. Once I turned that on, and retried, it was a success. Hope that helps anyone else.

Comment: I have done all of it as you said, even then I continue to get the error. @air_hadoken any idea?